# How to stop dynammically added labels to overlap

Tags: c#, winforms

Well I attempted to create labels next to each other but depending on the users input it can overlap the label beside it. I was wondering if theirs some sort of property that does not let the labels overlap.. I tried `AutoSize = true` method but I had no luck

The information was read from a xml file - they overlap horizontally

```
if (textReader.Name == "test")
{
   textReader.Read();
   XmlNodeType nType = textReader.NodeType;

   if (nType == XmlNodeType.Text)
   {
      Label l = new Label();

      System.Drawing.Point l1 = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 48 + a);
      l.Location = l1;
      l.Text = textReader.Value.ToString();
      l.Size = new Size(200, 50);

      tabPage2.Controls.Add(l);
      a += 35;
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean horizontally next to each other ?

Comment: yes i do sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AutoSize` to adjust width and height according to the text and `MaximumSize` to auto-wrap the text, remaining text will go the next line if its width exceeds 200.

```
l.AutoSize = true;
l.MaximumSize = new Size(200, 50);
```